# Replace blocks when broken in 1.9 minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want it so that when an anvil gets used up, it will put another one in it's place. Someone told me to use `/execute @a ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:snow 0 /setblock ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:air 0` , but it says

> "/setblock is not a valid number"

Comment: That command should work, if you type it *exactly* as written, but it does something *entirely* different from what you ask: It replaces snow blocks below any player with air.

Comment: Is this only one anvil (e.g. for an adventure map), or is this *any* anvil placed anywhere in the world?

Comment: The command itself worked perfectly fine for me. Although I'm not 100% sure what you want to do as you talk about anvils then use an example that removes snow below the player's feet, maybe explain your goal a bit more? Where is the anvil you want replaced, should it be replaced when it breaks or when it's damaged but not completely broken?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly... You want to refill the anvil when it's broke. So use this

```
/execute @e[name=Anvilblock,type=ArmorStand] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~ ~ air 0 /setblock ~ ~ ~ anvil
```

[image: The lever is only for toggle]
It would test for every ArmorStand that named "Anvilblock"
And if you want self-repair anvil just stand on where you want it to be placed and do

```
/summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:Anvilblock,Invisible:1,Marker:1}
```

Invisible make it invisible and Marker make It's hitbox's size to 0.
And when you don't want it anymore, Stand near it and do

```
/kill @e[type=ArmorStand,name=Anvilblock,r=2]
```

Be sure to turn off commandBlockOutput in /gamerule

Hope that's help!

Answer (score 0):

This should work. It doesn't detect for ANY anvil, only one at a specific coordinate, but it will work.
[image]
Take a repeating command block (always active) and place in the command `/testforblock <coords> anvil <data value1>`, then place a chain command block (conditional) with `/setblock <coords> anvil <data value2>`

Now you'll have to find the coords yourself, but for the data values:

- Data Value 1: **1** ;  Data Value 2: **9**
- Data Value 1: **2** ; Data Value 2: **10**
- Data Value 1: **3** ; Data Value 2: **11**

These are all your options for the data values, but they must be used together as a pair. Use whatever combination fits your scenario best.